# Data strucure used in Swift Var and internal mapping of var to types

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2

I am a beginner to Swift

In Objective we have independent types where they have their Data structure.
For example: NsArray, NsDictionary will have their own own data structure to store values.

What about Swift Var, if I don't explicitly specify the type of variable it will automatically assume it is a NSArray if array values are passed to it.

How will it distinguish between NsArray and NSMutableArray here?
Probably I got a solution for this which is let for immutable and var for mutable.

And how will the internal mapping of var to specific type happens?
Will the mapping happen at Run time? Will this cause slowness in my code if I don't specify the type explicitly?

And will let act as final in Swift?

Comment: Simple recommendation : In Swift use Foundation collection types (`NS...`) only if you have absolutely no choice.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Try to make one question by question, you've asked three different questions here. Also, there's [no need to thank](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3021/280621) here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Objective-C, there is a base class `NSArray`, and `NSMutableArray` is a subclass.

You can still use those classes in Swift if you so choose.

However, Swift is structured differently. In swift, you declare a variable or a *constant* to indicate if the container is mutable or not:

```
let aNonMutableDictionary: [String:String] = 
  ["key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"];
```

That creates a constant dictionary (the rough Swift equivalent of an NSDictionary)

If you want a mutable dictionary, use

```
var aMutableDictionary: [String:String] = 
  ["key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"];
```

The difference is the keywords `let` and `var`. The `var` keyword defines a variable (which is mutable.) The `let` keyword defines a constant (which is not mutable.)

You should read the Swift programming guide. The intro explains this quite clearly.

Answer (score 3):

> What about Swift Var, if I don't explicitly specify the type of variable it will automatically assume it is a NSArray if array values are passed to it.

Swift does not "automatically assume it is a NSArray". Swift's [`Array`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array) is distinct from `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray`. Swift will transparently bridge its `Array` type to `NSArray`.

> How will it distinguish between NSArray and NSMutableArray here?

Swift always bridges to `NSArray`, which can be passed into any call that expects either `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray` (because `NSMutableArray` is a subclass of `NSArray`). If you want an `NSMutableArray`, you'll need to explicitly specify that.

> Probably I got a solution for this which is let for immutable and var for mutable.

Yes, Swift uses a mutable version of `Array` when it's being assign to a `var` variable, and an immutable version when assigned to a `let` constant.

> And how will the internal mapping of var to specific type happens? Will the mapping happen at Run time?

What do you mean?

> Will this cause slowness in my code if I don't specify the type explicitly?

No. Swift will use an immutable data structure wherever possible, and this is favorable in terms of performance. Let the type inference of the compiler do its job.

Note: These concepts apply similarly to other types, like `String`/`NSString`/`NSMutableString` and `Dictionary`/`NSDictionary`/`NSMutableDictionary`.